# How can I define a derived field in apache solr

Tags: solr

I need to define a field that contains the Day from a date field.

Is it possible to define a field that is derived from another field in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking to a copyField but I'm not sure you can do what you want with that.

Otherwise, you can easily customize the index chain with a  UpdateRequestProcessor. In this case, just override the processAdd() method and manipulate as you want the incoming Solr(Input)Document